# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1 at forloop

Tags: java, android

I am trying to inflate an xml in my activity but i am getting this Arrayoutofbondexception at the for loop as its go inside the loop  I don't know why its giving me this cursor error can anyone help ?

```
public class ProfleList extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView txtProfileName,txtProfileDate,txtProfileTime,txtProfileLocation;
    LinearLayout linearlist ;

    DatabaseHelper mydb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profle_list);

        mydb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        long count = mydb.getCount();
        Log.d("count", "onCreate: "+count);

        if (count == 0){

        }else{
            ArrayList<ItemProfile> listprofile = mydb.profilelist();
            for (int i = 1; i < count; i++ ) {
                ItemProfile itemProfile = listprofile.get(i);

                linearlist = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutlist);
                View[] myView = new View[i];

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                myView[i] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_list, null);

                txtProfileName = (TextView)myView[i].findViewById(R.id.txtName);
                txtProfileDate = (TextView)myView[i].findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
                txtProfileTime = (TextView)myView[i].findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
                txtProfileLocation = (TextView)myView[i].findViewById(R.id.txtLocation);

                txtProfileName.setText(itemProfile.getProfileName());
                txtProfileDate.setText(itemProfile.getDay()+itemProfile.getMonth()+itemProfile.getYear());
                txtProfileTime.setText(itemProfile.getHour()+itemProfile.getMinute());
                txtProfileLocation.setText(itemProfile.getCity());
                linearlist.addView(myView[i]);


            }



        }




    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
View[] myView = new View[i];
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
myView[i] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_list, null);
```

you have defined an array of views with n elements, then you can not try to write at the index n....

try **instead between 0 and n-1**

## Example:

since you are looping from 1 and not zero, then use i-1 instead of i

```
for (int i = 1; i < count; i++ ) {
...
View[] myView = new View[i];
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
myView[i-1] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_list, null);
```

Comment: you mean i must change my for loop ?

Comment: you can either change the for loop and make it begin at zero Or displace the index of the vi using myViwe[i-1] instead of myView[i]....

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting the IOOBE because of these lines:

```
View[] myView = new View[i];
...
myView[i] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_list, null);
```

Lets say that i == 1. So you are creating an array of size 1 (new View[1]).
After that, you are trying to put an object in the array at position 1 (myView[1] =...) - but there is no index 1 in your array because the length of your array is 1 - so you have only index 0 at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
ArrayList<ItemProfile> listprofile = mydb.profilelist();
```

for getting all data with return type of

```
ArrayList<ItemProfile>
```

which store all the data from

```
i=0 to i<=listprofile.size();
```

so use

```
for(i=0,i=listprofile.size(), i++) 
{
//your code
}
```